# Add a new date record using procedural PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a Football Management System. Now, the reason why I added this question is because I keep getting "an error" while trying to submit a newly entered record using PHP and MySQL - to be frank, I want to know how to add a new record using the DATE field which has been declared as a FOREIGN KEY:

My source code fetching the records:

```
<?php
$count = 1;
$sel_query = "SELECT fixtures.fixture_date, players.player_name, playerfixtures.goals_scored 
              FROM playerfixtures 
              JOIN fixtures ON playerfixtures.fixture_id = fixtures.fixture_id 
              JOIN players ON playerfixtures.player_id = players.player_id 
              ORDER BY player_name asc;";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sel_query);
    while(
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["player_name"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["fixture_date"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["goals_scored"]; ?></td>
```

The following is a source code to enter a new record using a form:

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <table align="center">
        <br>
        <tr>
            <td>Add player fixture</td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Player:
                <input type="text" name="player_name" required>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fixture:
                <input type="date" name="fixture_date" required>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Goals:
                <input type="text" name="goals_scored" required>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Submit">
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on "I want to know how to add a new record using the DATE field which has been declared as a FOREIGN KEY:"?

Comment: Despect it's a fk maybe try to test if that date exist before , remember only to format like yyyy-MM-DD.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: If I had a problem with an INSERT, I'm not sure that I'd show the code for the SELECT !?!